# getting "FirebaseMLException: Input ByteBuffer should be direct ByteBuffer" while converting byte order to nativeOrder() in android studio

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to deploy a custom tensorflow lite model using FirebaseMLKit in Android Studio. But while doing so my model is taking ByteBuffer in LITTLE_ENDIAN, whereas my camera is providing byte array in BIG_ENDIAN byte order which is converted into ByteBuffer as shown below.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
```

So, I tried to change the order from BIG_ENDIAN to nativeOrder() which is LITTLE_ENDIAN to create FirebaseModelInputs object and passed it to the FirebaseModelInterpreter as shown below.

```
FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder().inputsBuilder.add(buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())).build();
return  interpreter.run(inputs,inputOutputOptions);
```

But I am getting following error on doing so. what should I do ?

```
com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Input ByteBuffer should be direct ByteBuffer
    at com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInputs$Builder.add(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter@@22.0.3:14)
    at com.example.facedect.facedetection.FaceDetectionProcessor.detectInImage(FaceDetectionProcessor.java:72)
    at com.example.facedect.VisionProcessorBase.detectInVisionImage(VisionProcessorBase.java:63)
    at com.example.facedect.VisionProcessorBase.process(VisionProcessorBase.java:34)
    at com.example.facedect.CameraSource$FrameProcessingRunnable.run(CameraSource.java:223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I tried to refer their [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/custom/FirebaseModelInputs.Builder) and found out that indirect buffer is not allowed.
Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC ByteBuffer.wrap() will create HeapByteBuffer, which is not a direct Bytebuffer. That's why FirebaseML is complaining.

Here are a few solution I can think of:

1. Convert your byteArray to LITTLE_ENDIAN and use another direct ByteBuffer to hold it. This might have performance issue because it has extra copy.
2. Take a look at new feature in Android Studio 4.1 [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#tensor-flow-lite-models). However to get best experience your model need to have [metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata).

For solution 1, try sth like this?

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
ByteBuffer directBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buffer.remaining());
directBuffer.put(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.remaining());
```

Then update the order for directBuffer like what you did. Hope it works!

Comment: Can you please share some code to implement 1st solution. I tried myself but was unable to do it.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird, allocateDirect should give you direct bytebuffer.. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer#direct-vs-non-direct-buffers

Comment: Can you take a look here? In sample app it also use allocateDirect and seems to work: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/java/custommodel/CustomImageClassifier.java#L272

Comment: Yes, the above link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/java/custommodel/CustomImageClassifier.java#L272 worked. Although solution 1 did not work